# react-native APK crash with "Unknown" error

Tags: react-native, babeljs, bundler, metro-bundler

My react-native developing environment is on Windows 7; worked fine until yesterday, but suddenly the APK reports an error after it loads the bundle.

The error Message:

```
Unknown
run
    NativeRunnable.java
handleCallback
    Handler.java:873
dispatchMessage
    Handler.java:99
dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29
loop
    Looper.java:193
run
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232
run
    Thread.java:764
```

I did google for the error, but no luck. I tried clearing the cache using `npm start -- --reset-cache`, but the error remains.
I found and tried [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41325888/8740349) but their solutions did not work either.

Error Logcat:

```
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative: com.facebook.jni.UnknownCppException: Unknown
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
06-16 14:30:16.144  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
06-16 14:30:16.152  5885  6735 E ReactNativeJNI: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit()
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit()
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
06-16 14:30:16.155  5885  6735 E ReactNativeJNI: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: AppRegistry.runApplication()
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: AppRegistry.runApplication()
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
06-16 14:30:16.156  5885  6735 E unknown:ReactNative:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
06-16 14:30:16.165  5885  5885 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
06-16 14:30:16.181  1571  1571 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3936256
06-16 14:30:16.187  1571  1571 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3936256
06-16 14:30:16.189  5885  6734 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() end
06-16 14:30:16.193  1571  1571 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3936256
06-16 14:30:16.224  5885  5885 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
06-16 14:30:16.224  5885  5885 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W unknown:ReactNative: Tried to enqueue runnable on already finished thread: 'js... dropping Runnable.
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {ef3c15} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {ef3c15} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:546)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:745)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:697)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:667)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:395)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.runOnQueue(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:70)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.runOnJSQueueThread(ReactContext.java:306)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher$ScheduleDispatchFrameCallback.doFrame(EventDispatcher.java:302)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:166)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:84)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
06-16 14:30:16.233  5885  5885 W MessageQueue:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
06-16 14:30:16.251  2042  2042 I GoogleInputMethod: onFinishInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
06-16 14:30:16.252  2042  2042 I GoogleInputMethod: onStartInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
06-16 14:30:16.255  5885  5902 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5dc78a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7055d70)
```

*Edit*: I have excluded from above log the parts that were the same as when the error was fixed.

Comment: I leaved the answer unaccepted in hopes of a solution, but will now accept my own answer, as it seems working around is the only way???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After debugging; disabling the `@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions` plugin (version `7.2.0`) and then clearing the cache (as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52383821/8740349)) fixed it for me:

### Steps:

1. Disable the `@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions` plugin, for example, I did just comment it out inside the `babel.config.js` file, like below:

   ````js
   module.exports = {
     presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
     plugins: [
       ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { decoratorsBeforeExport: false }],


       // Below plugin is unable to handle some of our arrow-functions,
       // which results in "Unknown" error after the app is launched.
       // ```
       // ['@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions', { spec: true }]
       // ```
     ]
   };
   ````
2. When the Packager is already running, close and/or terminate it using process-manager
3. For `react-native` `init` approach (without `expo`), run:

   ```
   npm start -- --reset-cache
   ```

(those who are using `expo-cli` should instead of above run `expo start -c`)

Above mentioned command is for me equal to removing the `%temp%/metro-cache` directory.

But still, cannot hurt to delete the `~/.babel.json` file (on Windows `%userProfile%/.babel.json` file) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107790/8740349), I mean, I have tested and the above-mentioned command did not remove and/or change the `.babel.json` file.

---

Logcat after fixed:

```
06-16 14:55:48.670  5885  6650 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() end
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedBlock.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS:
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycles are allowed, butcan result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need fora cycle.
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\base.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedCond.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedValue.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\base.js
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS:
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycles are allowed, butcan result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need fora cycle.
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedValue.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS:
06-16 14:55:49.374  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycles are allowed, butcan result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need fora cycle.
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedValue.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\derived\evaluateOnce.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedValue.js
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS:
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycles are allowed, butcan result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need fora cycle.
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\base.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedCond.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedValue.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\derived\evaluateOnce.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\base.js
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS:
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycles are allowed, butcan result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need fora cycle.
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\base.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedCond.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\utils.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedValue.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\derived\interpolate.js -> node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\base.js
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS:
06-16 14:55:49.375  5885  6652 W ReactNativeJS: Require cycles are allowed, butcan result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need fora cycle.
06-16 14:55:49.478  5885  6652 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "StormHoundsApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":201}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
06-16 14:55:49.749  5885  5885 I ReactNative: [GESTURE HANDLER] Initialize gesture handler for root view com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView{32e1596 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-768,1136 #c9}
06-16 14:55:51.469  1831  1854 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data toHAL, expected position 5387280 , only wrote 5234400
06-16 14:55:52.561  1912  2108 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@b89f9d4)
06-16 14:55:52.562  1912  1926 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@b89f9d4)
06-16 14:55:52.566  2537  2951 W ctxmgr  : [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10015):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000,0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2537). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
```

> To have a cleaner log, I have excluded from above the parts that were the same as when the error was present.

Comment: q= (-_- ) I am disabling the plugin just because `react-native` is unable to show a clear-error about what it does not like !! (good that I switched to `Flutter` nowadays - no more waste of time with confusing errors).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I stoped metro, cleaned the watchman list:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

and started it again, with the `--reset-cache` parameter:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

After deploying the app once more, the error was gone. I didn't need to do anything else.

I think some java files got corrupted (perhaps a racing condition, between updatas?) and nothing else seemed to trigger the recreation of those files again.